# error: type mismatch; found : (Int, Int) => Int required: Int

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala and confused why this code is giving me this error.

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int, i: Int): Int = {
  (m: Int, n: Int) => 
    if ((m - n) <= 0) 
      return i 
    else 
      div((m-n), n, (i+1)) 
}
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: _Offtopic._ Please, don't forget to [format](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) code in your answer. That's your second question where code examples are hard to read.

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't realize that was what it meant by format, I'll make sure to take care next time.

Comment: `return` is superflous, isn't it?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're returning a function rather than an `Int` like you're declaring.

Is this what you're trying to do:

```
def div(m: Int, n: Int, i: Int): Int = if ((m - n) <= 0) return i else div((m-n), n, (i+1))
```

Comment: I guess that was what I was trying. Did seem sort of redundant but the book I was trying things from did it in that format. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

`(x: A) => y: B` means an anonymous function of type `A => B`, so the expression you have between the braces is a function `(Int, Int) => Int`, and that's what gets returned.

Answer (score 0):

You use a big number of superflous stuff, the `return`- keyword, parenthesis, and the whole (m: Int, n:Int) => - part.

```
def div (m: Int, n: Int, count: Int): Int =
  if ((m - n) <= 0) count else div (m - n, n, count + 1)
```

If you like to use a match, you could do it this way:

```
def div (m: Int, n: Int, count: Int = 1): Int = (m - n) match {
  case (diff: Int) if (diff <= 0) => count
  case _ => div (m - n, n, count + 1) }
```

(note the default-argument of count = 1).
m,n,i are a little bit too much short-named variables for my taste. Beneath `count`, `nominator, denominator` would fit.

However, the implentation returns

```
(0 to 2).map (x => div (14+x, 5, 1))
res61: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(3, 3, 4)
```

where I would expect (2, 3, 3) - you're rounding in the opposite direction.

```
if ((m - n) < 0) i-1 else ...
```

would fix that - changing the comparator, and returning i-1 (count-1).

However, this is not testet for values including 0 and negative values.